# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед вторым союзом «И», если он не соединяет однородные члены предложения, а относится к другой части?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, авторская-пунктуация, и

К примеру, есть предложение:

> Маша пошла в магазин, купила макароны и сметану и вернулась домой.

В предложении однородными членами выступают глаголы «пошла», «купила» и «вернулась» — если бы не было уточнения «и сметану», запятая не ставилась бы: `Маша пошла в магазин, купила макароны и вернулась домой.`

Но как поступать в исходном предложении, когда подряд стоят два союза «И», но они относятся к разным частям предложения?

Нужно ли или можно ли ставить запятую, чтобы сделать интонационную паузу:

```
Маша пошла в магазин, купила макароны и сметану(,) и вернулась домой.
```

Либо она недопустима? Если возможно, скиньте, пожалуйста, правило — я не нашёл.

Знаю, что можно переписать предложение, чтобы избавиться от одного из повторяющихся союзов, но вопрос именно про конкретный случай — нужно/можно ли ставить запятую или нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном простом предложении союзы ***и*** не являются повторяющимися (как, например, в таком: *Маша купила и молоко, и сметану*). Каждый из них соединяет однородные члены: сказуемые (как Вы правильно отметили) и дополнения — ***молоко и сметану*** (*сметана* не является уточнением). Союзы относятся не к разным частям предложения, а к разным (своим) однородным членам.

Аналогичные примеры из Национального корпуса русского языка:

*...он был живой, теплый, прыгал, скакал, блеял и, главное, ― **ел** из рук **морковку и хлеб и пил** молоко.* [Н. А. Лухманова. Девочки (1894)]

*Билль **сказал**, что у них все есть, и даже фазаны к жаркому, **поблагодарил за молоко и хлеб и предложил** хозяевам вместе пообедать.* [К. М. Станюкович. Похождения одного матроса (1900)]

У союза ***и*** есть не только соединительная функция, но и присоединительная.

[**Присоединительные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120)

> Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат **дополнительные разъяснения или замечания**, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми (реже используются тире, точка, многоточие). Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами *даже, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, и притом, причём, **и** (**‘и притом’**), да, да и, да и вообще, да и только* и др.
>
> *А Рудин заговорил о самолюбии, **и очень дельно заговорил** (Т.); Передавая им эти сведения, он поступил нехорошо, **и знал это***.

Как видим, присоединительный союз ***и*** имеет значение ***и притом***, в приведенных примерах его можно заменить этим сочетанием, чего нельзя сказать о предложении из вопроса. Можно, конечно, представить какие-то авторские изыски, но в такой бытовой фразе это маловероятно. Интонационная небольшая пауза при прочтении данного предложения не является грамматической и оснований для постановки запятой не дает.

Если представить себе такой контекст, в котором говорится, что Маша не собиралась возвращаться домой, а хотела пойти куда-то еще, то тогда возможны такие варианты:

*Маша пошла в магазин, купила макароны и сметану — и вернулась домой.*

*Маша пошла в магазин, купила макароны и сметану... и вернулась домой.*

> 3. При указании на внезапность, неожиданность наступления действия или при наличии оттенка противопоставления перед союзом ***и***, соединяющим два однородных сказуемых, ставится тире, реже — многоточие.

[**Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100)